# Prove that $\phi(n^2-1)|n!$, where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> **Example 1.32.** Prove that for any even positive integer $n$, $n^2-1$ divides $2^{n!}-1$.
>
> [From: Titu Andreescu, Dorin Andrica, Zuming Feng, *104 Number Theory Problems: From the Training of the USA IMO Team*.]

Now I took $n=4$ and made the following observation $\phi(4^2-1)=\phi(15)=8|4!$ Now if we assume that $\phi(n^2-1)|n!\Rightarrow n!=k\phi(n^2-1)$, then $$2^{\phi(n^2-1)}\equiv 1\pmod {n^2-1}\Rightarrow 2^{n!}\equiv1\pmod{n^2-1}$$ And we are done.

I tried to prove this in the following manner: Since $\phi(n)$ is a multiplicative function:$\phi(n^2-1)=\phi(n-1)\phi(n+1)\leq (n-2)(n).$ Now since the values of $\phi(n-1)$ and $\phi(n+1)$ lie within $[1,n]$, all we have to show is that they are not equal. Because if they are then $\phi(n^2-1)\not| n!$ because one them "eats" their common multiple. Beyond this I am clueless.

Comment: Are you sure that $\phi(n-1)$ and $\phi(n+1)$ cannot be equal? Try values $n=8,636,1016,\dots$

Comment: Note that $\phi(n^2-1) \mid n!$ is a stronger assertion than you need to show that $(n^2-1) \mid (2^{n!}-1)$. The latter is easily deduced from what you have.

Comment: The title does not agree with the question.

Comment: The title is false for $n=3$. Beyond that, it seems to hold. The proof shouldn't be too hard, although probably a bit laborious. The rough idea: The integers $n-1$ and $n+1$ are "almost coprime" (namely, their gcd is $1$ or $2$), and so we have "almost" $\phi\left(n^2-1\right) = \phi\left(n-1\right)\phi\left(n+1\right)$. Ideally, we would like the numbers $\phi\left(n-1\right)$ and $\phi\left(n+1\right)$ to be two distinct elements of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,n\right\}$, which would immediately show that their product divides $n!$. The world is not that fair, and so these two numbers might fail ...

Comment: ... to be distinct, and the case of the gcd being $2$ comes with its own issues. But I believe these are surmountable hurdles. (For example, the almost-universal evenness of $\phi$-values allows us to replace one of these two numbers by its half if the two numbers are equal. We then have to get a factor $2$ from elsewhere, but there is plenty of supply in a big factorial.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg the precondition to the problem mentions "any even".

Comment: And the answer below by @FrancescoBaccetti is really tiny, elegant and precise ...

Comment: I'm talking about the title though, which for all practical purposes is a separate problem.

Comment: It's true, indeed!

Answer (score 4):

You have $$ 2^{n!} \equiv 1\ \pmod{n+1} $$
         $$ 2^{n!} \equiv 1\ \pmod{n-1} $$
You have to prove that  $\phi(n-1)\mid n!$ and that $\phi(n+1)\mid n!$ but as you said $\phi(n+1) $ and $\phi(n-1)$ are both smaller than $n$ and $\gcd(n+1,n-1)=1$, so $$(n^2-1)\mid 2^{n!}- 1$$